# Concerns with Network Solutions Incorporated improper business practices

Tags: dns, registration

This subject is informative in nature but also asking for asolution. I am aware that this is a knowledge base forum but frankly I do not know where to start sharing this issue.

I have been doing business with NSI for last 25 years.  I have over a dozed domain registered under their chart. I have had no problem with the safety of my ownership of my domain names but lately have experienced great inconveniences with unauthorized credit card charges.

I am very concerned as to the NSI trend engagements in very aggressive marketing practices with existing Domain name owners. Frankly, every time that I login the NSI dashboard for domain name maintenance, I  find harder and harder to find the Domain name  configuration board.   NSI excessively pushes into buying service not solicited or needed at all. Worst of all is that NSI website is burdened with deceived links leading to  credit card charge for services that never had a  need not interest. I considered many of these links to be a improper business practice that compromises stability of Domain Owners business owner.

The worst chapter of the story is that support in not available to fix this account issues. Recently, I detected from muy account a charge for a  web site and email forwarding service never solicited in the past . The hidden fee was ongoing for several month but no my account manager never answers my email complains.

At the end, I had no other choice but to file a credit card bank claim .  This is a great inconvenience for both, NSI and the domain name owner because NSI holds the registration services of all my domains which leaves me with the great concerns as what may happen next in line.

Please, I will like your comments about this and how will any of you will handle this situation.  Moving domain to a new register is a very expensive since NSI demands about $35 per domain to authorized the transfer.

Comment: "NSI demands about $35 per domain to authorized the transfer. " In gTLDs this is strictly forbidden (as long as the domain is not expired already of course), so I doubt this is really the core of your problem. You can be more ontopic about domain name questions on [webmasters.se] for example, but remain factual, with clear examples if you want useful help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only offer that I had the same frustrations with NS after years of service.  Finally did do a transfer and glad I did.  I do not remember paying a fee.  But yes, it was a bit of effort.